# Diagnose a damaged lens from focus test results

Tags: lens, focus, repair, vintage

I have a lens that gives perfectly decent results at f/22 and f/32. Here's its capture of [an ISO 12233 test chart](http://www.graphics.cornell.edu/~westin/misc/res-chart.html):

[image: SMC Pentax-A 135mm/2.8 at f/32]

It's not the sharpest lens I own, but whaddaya want, it's a quarter century old design. ([SMC Pentax-A 135mm/2.8](http://www.pentaxforums.com/lensreviews/SMC-Pentax-A-135mm-F2.8-Lens.html))

This lens starts getting soft at f/16 and below. Between about f/11 and f/5.6, it's reasonably sharp in the center, with an increasing amount of that "vaseline on the skylight filter" look at the edges. By f/4, the soft focus effect reaches the center, but it's not so bad that you couldn't purposely use it as a soft-focus lens. At f/2.8, it's an, um, "creative" *dreamy* lens. Yeah, that's it, dreamy:

[image: SMC Pentax-A 135mm/2.8 at f/2.8]

Note the doubled image of the triangles at the edge of the test chart.

What does this test result mean?

I've asked two lens repair companies to quote me on a repair for this. One said "talk to Pentax," and the other didn't even bother responding.

I ended up buying a different copy, which performs properly through the full aperture range.

That leaves me with a set of choices:

1. Sell it, including these test chart images of course, hoping that someone wants a "creative" lens.
2. Keep it and use it as such myself. But, I have Photoshop, so what do I need with a soft-focus lens?
3. Take it apart and try to fix it. If it doesn't work out, hey, I get a pile of bare lens elements to play with. That could be fun.

There is no visible problem when looking through the bare lens, and it rattles only a tiny bit when you shake it hard. I'm guessing the tiny rattle is a loose lens element. Does the test image support that guess?

Comment: Just out of curiosity. What is the price of such lens?

Comment: @fasttouch: They're selling on eBay for US $125-150, at the moment.

Comment: Then I would say have fun with it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From an optical testing standpoint the main aberration that shows up on axis is spherical -  and it varies only due to (F/#)^4, which explains why you are getting a soft focus at a larger aperture. If you look at the top and bottom the the image you see triangles aren't imaged the same, which would probably be astigmatism. I could tell you more if I saw more pictures, but that doesn't really matter; I think one of your lens elements is de-spaced and/or de-centered. I don't know how easy it is to fix it though; I have never aligned a lens myself, though I have seen instructions on the internet on how to do it. If you have another copy I see no reason not to mess around with it.

Comment: I agree with @Alex. Hopefully it's the front element (easiest to fix), which will be held in place by either a threaded ring with writing on it, or a black threaded metal ring. The latter will have two notches in it for a lens wrench to grip; the former will have no notches but _may_ be able to be tightened with your fingertips (if loose).  If you are confident in your abilities and have the right tools (size 0 and 00 phillips screwdrivers, lens wrench, rubber grip cloth, fine toothed tweezers, microfibre cloth, pressurised air), I would go with option 3).